# Input contracted when in focus - Chrome

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, boxsizer

I have a simple input with some styles.

```css
 input {
     display: block;
     width: 100%;
     padding: 4px 6px;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
     box-sizing: border-box; 
    }
```

```html
  <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
```

The code works just fine with Firefox. However, in Chrome, when the input is focused it get shrunk a little bit (smaller than in normal state). 
I've tried to apply border-box sizing on this input but the problem still retains. How should I fixed that?

Comment: If you do input: focus{outline:0;} will take focus away and then you can manipulate it from there........

Comment: Are you using any of the default class from twitter-bootstrap???. You can use class=form-group to wrap your form and class=form-control for your input box. That should be able to render almost exactly in every browser.

Comment: @JosephCC I use bootstrap but I don't want to wrap my input as form-control because I want to style it differently. I've tried to apply `input:focus{ outline: 0; }` and it's not working

Comment: *:focus{outline:none!important; border:0!important; box-shadow:none!important;}.  Try that....

Answer (score 1):

Use the `:focus` pseudo class.

```
input:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Like this: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1m9bzbqL/).

It works fine for me in Chrome and Firefox as well. Also worth to consider of using [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) (or something similar), to avoid (or fix) the browsers default css attriibute settings.